# F-test: How to use type I error to compute type II error?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

Here is the conclusion from the reference

https://www.real-statistics.com/chi-square-and-f-distributions/power-of-two-sample-variance-testing/

Let $s_1^2$ and $s_2^2$ represent the variances of two independent samples of size $n_1$ and $n_2.$ We know that
$$\dfrac{s^2_1/\sigma^2_1}{s^2_2/\sigma^2_2}\sim  F_{n_1-1,n_2-1}.$$
Let $x_{crit}$ be the critical value based on the null hypothesis with significance level $\alpha:$
$$x_{crit} = F_{n_1-1,n_2-1}^{-1}(\alpha)$$
For the one-tailed test

$$H_0: \sigma_1^2 ≥ \sigma_2^2\ i.e.\ \lambda = \dfrac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_1^2}\geq1,$$
we have the beta value:
$$\beta = F_{n_1-1,n_2-1}(x_{crit}/\lambda).$$

I don't know how to obtain the value of $\beta$ when we know $\alpha?$ If we use $T/F$ to represent accept/reject $H_0;$ $1/0$ to represent $H_0$ is true/false. Then we have conditions:

$$P(F|1) = \alpha = F_{n_1-1,n_2-1}(x_{crit});$$
$$P(1) = F_{n_1-1,n_2-1}(\lambda).$$
We want to compute:
$$\beta = P(T|0)?$$

I don't think the conditions are enough to compute $\beta.$

Comment: You can compute $\beta$ only if you have a _specific_ numerical value of $\lambda$ in mind. Power can be computed only as probability of detecting a particular alternative.

Comment: when we have value $\lambda = \lambda_0,$ how can we represent $\beta?$

Comment: Perhaps see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2253173/how-to-find-the-type-2-error-of-an-f-test-for-equality-of-variances).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Power of 2-Sample F test for Population Variances.**

***Null and one-sided alternative hypotheses:*** Suppose you have random samples, both of size $n_i=n_2=20$ from normal populations
with variances $\sigma_1^2, \sigma_2^2,$ respectively.
You want to use their sample variances to test whether to reject $H_0: \sigma_1^2 = \sigma_2^2$ against $H_a: \sigma_1^2 > \sigma_2^2.$ Sometimes the hypotheses
are written as $H_0: \Lambda =\frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_2^2} = 1$ against $H_a: \Lambda > 1.$

***Null distribution:*** If $H_0$ is true, then the distribution of the ratio $R$ of sample variances is given by
$R = \frac{S_1^2}{S_2^2} \sim F(n_1-1, n_2-1),$ which is $R \sim F(19,19)$ in our example. It seems natural to reject $H_0$ in favor of $H_a$ if $R$ is sufficiently large. [The variance ratio is sometimes called `F` in computer printouts, but
I am using $R$ here to avoid confusion between the test statistic and its distribution.]

***Critical value:*** In particular, one can use printed tables of $F$ distributions (or software) to find
the critical value $c$ for a one-sided test at the 5% level. In our example $c = 2.168$
is found using R as below. Roughly speaking $R = S_1^2/S_2^2$ needs to exceed about $R = 2.17$ in order for $H_0$ to be rejected.

```
c = qf(.95, 19, 19);  c
[1] 2.168252
```

One may say that the significance level $\alpha = 0.05 - 5\%$ is the probability
of a Type I error:  $\alpha = P(\mathrm{Rej}\,|\,\Lambda=1).$

***Type II error and power:*** The question now arises, how likely are we to reject $H_0,$ if
$\Lambda = \frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_2^2} = 4.$ That is, how likely are we to reject
if the first population variance is four times as big as the second population variance?

The *power* of the test to detect this ratio $\Lambda = 4$ in population variances
is probability of rejecting $H_0$ for the particular alternative with $\Lambda = 4;$
we might designate the power as
$$P(\mathrm{Rej}\,|\,\Lambda=4) = \pi(4) = \pi(\Lambda=4),$$
depending upon what information is obvious from the immediate context.

A Type II error occurs if $H_a$ is true and we fail to reject.
We might designate the probability of a Type II in this situation as
$$P(\mathrm{Fail\,to\,Rej}\,|\,\Lambda=4) = \beta(4) = \beta(\Lambda=4) = 1 - \pi(\Lambda=4).$$

In general, for independent normal samples,
$$\frac{S_1^2/\sigma_1^2}{S_2^2/\sigma_2^2} = \frac{S_1^2}{S_2^2}/\Lambda = R/\Lambda \sim F(n_1-1,n_2-1).$$

***Power computation for example:*** In our example, it follows that $\beta(4)=0.0956, \pi(4)=0.9044$ can be found in R as shown below. (Many printed tables of F distributions lack the detail to find these
exact probabilities.)

```
1 - pf(c/4, 19, 19)
[1] 0.904437
pf(c/4, 19, 19)
[1] 0.09556305
```

So with two samples of size twenty, we are reasonably sure (power about 90%) that an F-test will
detect that the first population has four times the variance as the second.

***Software procedures:*** Many kinds of statistical software have 'power and sample size' procedures used to
find the power for given sample sizes or the sample sizes needed to achieve a desired
power. In Minitab software, one specifies the ratio $\lambda = \sqrt{\Lambda}$ of population *standard deviations* one hopes to detect. Many of these procedures
give results only for the 'balanced' case where $n_1 = n_2.$ Minitab output for
our example follows:

```
Power and Sample Size 

Test for Two Standard Deviations

Testing (StDev 1 / StDev 2) = 1 (versus >)
Calculating power for (StDev 1 / StDev 2) = ratio
α = 0.05
Method:  F Test

       Sample
Ratio    Size     Power
    2      20  0.904437

The sample size is for each group.
```

[image]

***Simulation:*** It is sometimes convenient to approximate the power provided by particular
sample sizes by using a simulation. [Notes: (a) Sample sizes are equal here, but they need not be. Population means are not relevant to the situation and are both set to $0.$ (c) With 100,000 iterations, it is reasonable to expect about two place accuracy for power.]

```
set.seed(302)
r = replicate( 10^5, var(rnorm(20,0,2))/var(rnorm(20,0,1)) )
c = qf(.95, 19, 19)
mean(r > c)
[1] 0.90388  # aprx power
```

*Note:* If you have the budget for $10$ additional subjects, it
is better to increase both samples to size $25,$ increasing the power
of $95.3\%,$ rather than to increase one sample to $30$ and leave
the other at $20,$ obtaining power $94.5\%,$ Balanced designs are
more efficient.

```
set.seed(303)
r = replicate( 10^5, var(rnorm(25,0,2))/var(rnorm(25,0,1)) )
c = qf(.95, 24, 24)
mean(r > c)
[1] 0.95346

set.seed(304)
r = replicate( 10^5, var(rnorm(30,0,2))/var(rnorm(20,0,1)) )
c = qf(.95, 29, 19)
mean(r > c)
[1] 0.94472
```